# Compute the limit $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{4x^2+4y^2}{2\sin(x^2+y^2)+x^2+y^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

**Compute the limit** $$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{4x^2+4y^2}{2\sin(x^2+y^2)+x^2+y^2}$$

**My insights:**

$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{4(x^2+y^2)}{2\sin(x^2+y^2)+x^2+y^2}$

Division in nominator,denominator by $x^2+y^2$ gives:

$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{4}{2*1+\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}}$

$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{4}{2+0+0}$ = 2

**Correct answer (as shown in the answer sheet): $\frac{4}{3}$**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: your limit is equivalent to
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{4t^2}{2 \sin (t^2) + t^2}.
$$
Indeed, $t=x^2+y^2 \to 0$ as $(x,0) \to (0,0)$, and you may apply a general theorem on the limit of composite functions.

Comment: I see. Do you have any idea where in my solution I was wrong? Btw, thank you for the hint. It's perfect.

Comment: Sure: $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} + \frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}=1$, while you believe that it is zero.

Comment: Can you explain please why does it equal to $1$?

Comment: Just add and observe that the numerator equals the denominator. Each fraction has no limit, anyway.

Comment: Oh hahaha! Thank you!!